# Is there any way to create a const &'static CStr?

Tags: rust, ffi

I haven't found anything in the standard library about how to make a `const &'static CStr`. I've tried to make my own macro to convert a `&'static str` literal to a `&'static CStr`:

```rust
macro_rules! cstr {
    ($e: expr) => {{
        const buffer: &str = concat!($e, "\0");
        unsafe {std::ffi::CStr::from_bytes_with_nul_unchecked(buffer.as_bytes())}
    }}                                                                           
}
```

It has a couple problems:

1. If `expr` contains a null byte, it invokes undefined behavior
2. `str::as_bytes` is not `const`, so the `&CStr` is not const

Comment: Are you actually certain that you need `&'static CStr`, particularly the `'static` part? Where does that exotic requirement come from?

Comment: I don't need it to be static, but what I'm looking for is a `&CStr` which references memory stored in the binary, like a `&str` litteral does. It just seems like it should be possible.

Comment: That *massively* changes the question. I'm going to keep the original answer for posterity, as it *is* possible, and I'll give you the non-`'static` version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Rust 1.46.0 (current beta toolchain at time of writing) this is possible, now that `std::mem::transmute` is stable as a `const fn`. You can also use `const fn`s to check that the contents of the string are valid (i.e. no null bytes), since you can use basic conditional expressions and loops as well. Panicking via `panic!` isn't yet possible in constant contexts, but you can use implicitly panicking code (e.g. `[][0]`) to raise an error at compile time. All told, here's a fully functional example that uses nothing but `const fn`s and declarative macros to allow creating `&'static CStr`s in constant contexts, including checking the contents for illegal null bytes.

```
#[allow(unconditional_panic)]
const fn illegal_null_in_string() {
    [][0]
}

#[doc(hidden)]
pub const fn validate_cstr_contents(bytes: &[u8]) {
    let mut i = 0;
    while i < bytes.len() {
        if bytes[i] == b'\0' {
            illegal_null_in_string();
        }
        i += 1;
    }
}

macro_rules! cstr {
    ( $s:literal ) => {{
        $crate::validate_cstr_contents($s.as_bytes());
        unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<_, &std::ffi::CStr>(concat!($s, "\0")) }
    }};
}

const VALID: &std::ffi::CStr = cstr!("hello world");
// const INVALID: &std::ffi::CStr = cstr!("hello\0world");

fn main() {
    println!("Output: {:?}", VALID);
}
```

Note that this does rely on implementation details of `CStr` (specifically that the layout is compatible with `[u8]`), so this shouldn't be used in production code.

Comment: As of Rust 1.57.0, [`panic!()` can be used in `const fn`](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/12/02/Rust-1.57.0.html#panic-in-const-contexts) and you can simplify the panic here and use a custom message.

Comment: As of Rust 1.72.0, [`CStr::from_bytes_with_nul` can be used in `const fn`](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2023/08/24/Rust-1.72.0.html#stabilized-apis) so you can avoid `transmute`, although `Result::unwrap` still isn't const stable, so you have to manually panic.

Answer (score 6):

Since Rust 1.77.0, on edition 2021 and forwards, you can create `&CStr` literals with the `c` prefix:

```rust
const FOO: &core::ffi::CStr = c"Hello, world!";
```

This allows using escapes (even non-UTF-8), checks for interior NUL bytes (and reject them), and properly adds a trailing NUL.

On older versions, you can use the [`cstr`](https://docs.rs/cstr) crate:

```rust
const FOO: &core::ffi::CStr = cstr::cstr!(b"Hello, world!");
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a crate for this, [byte_strings](https://docs.rs/byte-strings/0.1.3). To summarize the crate, the basic idea is to use a union with a `&'static [u8]` (or `&'static str`) member and a `&'static CStr` member:

```rust
union transmute {
    src: &'static [u8],
    dst: &'static ::std::ffi::CStr,
}
```

Since constructing unions is `const` and accessing a `const` union's field is also `const`, reading `dst` is effectively a `const` mem::transmute. Since `CStr` is currently just a wrapper for a `[c_char]`, a `&[u8]` can be safely trunsmuted to `&CStr`, however, in the future, the representation of `CStr`s will likely change. You can do a sanity check that `&CStr` is the same size as `&[u8]` by using a little hack with the lengths of zero-size arrays:

```rust
const transmute_is_sound_guard: [(); std::mem::size_of::<&'static [u8]>()]
    = [(); std::mem::size_of::<&'static ::std::ffi::CStr>()];
```

If they don't have the same size, Rust's type checker will complain. **Bringing it all together, you can create a macro to make a `const &'static CStr`**:

```rust
use std::ffi::CStr;
use std::mem::size_of;

macro_rules! unsafe_cstr {
    ($e: expr) => {{
        union Transmute {
            src: &'static str,
            dst: &'static CStr,
        }

        const _TRANSMUTE_CHECK: [(); size_of::<&'static str>()]
            = [(); size_of::<&'static CStr>()];

        const RES: &'static CStr = unsafe {
            (Transmute { src: concat!($e, "\0") }).dst
        };

        RES
    }}                                                                           
}

fn main() {
    const C: &'static CStr = unsafe_cstr!("Hello, World!");
    println!("{:?}", C)
}
```

Unfortunately, this macro still isn't safe, because it doesn't check for null bytes within the `&str` slice, which can only be done with a procedural macro. The byte_strings crate [contains such a macro](https://docs.rs/byte-strings-proc-macro/0.1.1/src/byte_strings_proc_macro/identity_non_null.rs.html#18-50), as well as macros for concatenating byte string literals and other convenience macros.

Comment: lovely unsafe_cstr answer, thank you. Surely this has made it to the mainstream by now? But I don't find such a feature. And then I found this: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/75401 and https://crates.io/crates/cstr

Answer (score 2):

A `CStr` is a [*borrowed type*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html) and, as such, isn't made "on its own". Below the hood, it isn't much more than a reference to a [`CString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html), and can be created from either:

- Borrowing a `CString` (obvious). The original (source) `CString` must not be dropped and the lifetime of `CStr` is only valid for as long as the source exists
- From a slice of bytes, via [`CStr::from_bytes_with_nul`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html#method.from_bytes_with_nul). The `CStr` is only valid for as long as the original slice (which itself is only valid for as long as the source data allocated *somewhere*)

Creating a `CStr` through a `CString` is straightforward:

```
let cstring:CString = CString::new("foobar".as_bytes()).unwrap();
let cstr:&CStr = cstring.as_c_str();
println!("{:?}", cstr);
```

Converting an existing slice is also straightforward:

```
let cstr2:&CStr = CStr::from_bytes_with_nul("foobar\0".as_bytes()).unwrap();
println!("{:?}", cstr2);
```

Do note that the lifetime of these will evidently, again, depend on the lifetime of whatever you used to create the `&CStr` - as indicated by the lifetime parameter on its declaration

---

**Kept for posterity**: `'static` was not a hard requirement

To create a `const &'static CStr`, you're going to struggle, and you're going to need an external crate for a specific macro (`lazy_static`), but it is doable, like so:

```
#[macro_use] extern crate lazy_static;
use std::ffi::CStr;

lazy_static! {
    static ref FOO:&'static CStr = unsafe {
        CStr::from_bytes_with_nul_unchecked("foobar\0".as_bytes())
    };
}

fn test(input: &'static CStr) {
    println!("{:?}", FOO.to_str());
}

fn main() {
    test(&FOO);
}
```

The point of `lazy_static` is to allow function calls when defining static references; we can leverage this to construct our `CStr` on-the-fly, and since it is a static reference, borrowing it is valid for up to and including `'static`. Mission accomplished.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was a little unclear with my earlier comment. `const` is the hard constraint, and it was my understanding that all `const` references must be `'static`. But if that's not the case, `'static` is not a constraint.